# How to convert string currency value in integer

Tags: javascript

I have string like "17,420 ฿". How to change this as integer value. I have done

```
var a = "17,420 ฿"
var b = a.split(' ')[0];
console.log(Number(b))
```

But I am getting NaN because of `,`.
So i have done like below

```
var c = b.replace( /,/g, "" );
console.log(Number(c));
```

Now, I am getting 17420 as an integer.

But, is there any better method to do it.

Comment: Do you want `17420` or `17.42`?

Comment: I believe the question is if there is a more efficient way to do it. OP already has a working solution I reckon.

Comment: @ADyson there are other connotations than that of American standards. European connotation usually use `,` as a decimal separator, and `.` as a thousand separator, where the americanized connotation is the exact opposite.

Comment: @Martin I realise that. That was my point, in fact. I made an answer on that basis. I was assuming OP was having difficulty because JS (and most other programming languages) uses the US/UK cultural convention by default. But maybe their code is working as desired and they just want a code review, it's not 100% clear in the question.

Comment: use a library for that. No need to reinvent the wheel. https://www.npmjs.com/package/currency.js

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think questions about improving working code belong on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could start by stripping off anything that's NOT a number or a decimal point. `string.replace` and a bit of RegExp will help. Then use `parseFloat` or `Number` to convert that number-like string into a number. Don't convert to an integer (a decimal-less number), since you're dealing with what appears to be currency.

```
const num = parseFloat(str.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''))
```

But then at the end of the day, you should NOT be doing string-to-number conversion. Store the number as a number, then format it to a string for display, NOT the other way around.

Comment: RegEx is the way to go imo too.

Comment: Do note that regional formatting can influence what the correct regex would be. For example, `.` could mean *thousand* separator in some cultures, which can end up reducing `1.000` to just `1` if parsed, thus the correct thing would be to remove the character. Also, in those cases (and some others) a comma could be the decimal separator, thus `1,23` could suddenly be turned to `123`. In THAT case, comma should be replaced by a dot. But you should be careful not to wipe it out when removing other dots. Other cultures might have other separators, like a space. TL;DR - it's a hard problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily remove all non-digits with a regex like so:

```
a.replace(/\D/g, '');
```

Then use parseInt to get integer value:

```
parseInt(b);
```

Combined:

```
var result = parseInt(a.replace(/\D/g, ''));
```

Comment: This will yield the incorrect result, if the input has decimal fractions, e.g., `$3.50` would have both the dollar sign and the decimal separator stripped and the result would be `350`.

Answer (score 1):

Split for the `,` and then join via `.` and then parse it as a float. Use `.toFixed()` to determine how many decimal places you wish to have.

```js
console.log(
  parseFloat("17,420 ฿".split(' ')[0].split(',').join('.')).toFixed(3)
);
```

As a function:

```js
const convert = (str) => {
  return parseFloat(str.split(' ')[0].split(',').join('.')).toFixed(3)
}

console.log(convert("17.1234 $"));
console.log(convert("17 $"));
console.log(convert("17,2345 $"));
```

Alternative:

```js
const convert = (str) => {
  let fixedTo = 0;
  const temp = str.split(' ')[0].split(',');
  if(temp.length > 1){
    fixedTo = temp[1].length;
  }

  return parseFloat(temp.join('.')).toFixed(fixedTo)
}

console.log(convert("17,1234 $"));
console.log(convert("17,123 $"));
console.log(convert("17,1 $"));
console.log(convert("17 $"));
```

Comment: Couldn't the `toFixed(3)`, create problems towards numbers like `650 ฿`?

Comment: Since it's not really a decimal, but a thousands indicator.

Comment: See, in the Netherlands here 650 and 650.000 is not the same.

Comment: @Sparky well, for OP `17,420` is already NOT the same as `17.420`. If that's a bank account, somebody just lost 99.9% of their savings.

Comment: @Sparky I've provided an alternative in any case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `parseInt` after removing the comma

```
var a = "17,420 ฿"
console.log(parseInt(a.replace(",",""), 10))

o/p -> 17420
```

Comment: How is this better compared to what OP is doing? He is already stripping the comma and parsing the result. This approach ignores the existence of fractions but otherwise is the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
Number(a.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ""))
```

This will replace all not numbers chars... is that helpful?